# How do I expand a range into a list in vimscript?

Tags: vi, vim

I'd like to automatically take a visually selected block of text, such as 
`51-100`, and have it expanded into `51,52,53,...,99,100`.

Is there an easy way to do this in vimscript?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me propose the following implementation.

```
vnoremap <silent> <leader># :<c-u>call ExpandRange()<cr>
function! ExpandRange()
    norm! gvy
    let n = matchlist(@", '\(\d\+\)\s*-\s*\(\d\+\)')[1:2]
    if len(n) != 2 || +n[0] > +n[1]
        return
    end
    exe 'norm! gvc' . join(range(n[0], n[1]), ',')
endfunction
```

If it is guaranteed by the range notation that there is no whitespace around
numbers, the second statement of `ExpandRange()` can be simplified by using
the `split()` function,

```
    let n = split(@", '-')
```

Note that the text denoting a range is put into the unnamed register.  If it
is preferable to leave the register untouched, modify `ExpandRange()` to save
its state beforehand and restore it afterwards.

```
function! ExpandRange()
    let [qr, qt] = [getreg('"'), getregtype('"')]
    norm! gvy
    let n = matchlist(@", '\(\d\+\)\s*-\s*\(\d\+\)')[1:2]
    call setreg('"', qr, qt)
    if len(n) != 2 || +n[0] > +n[1]
        return
    end
    exe 'norm! gv"_c' . join(range(n[0], n[1]), ',')
endfunction
```